# Execute JAR on remote server through PHP

Tags: php, server

I have a remote linux server, that contains a jar file, that I would like to be able to open.
Its path is `/home/files/java/exec.jar`.

I tried executing it through PHP, and I needed to put it in the folder `/var/www/html/run_jar.php`.

Here is the code I achieved:

```php
<?php
$path = '/home/server/spigot-1.13.2.jar';
$exists = file_exists($path);
if($exists){
    echo 'File exists, running...<br>';
    $msg = shell_exec('java -jar '.$path);
    echo '"'.$msg.'"';
} else {
    echo 'File doesn\'t exist';
}
?>
```

However when opening the php on google chrome, it says the file doesn't exist, when it clearly does.
Are there any permission I should be aware of? And how would I manage to actually run the jar on the remote server? Thanks!

Comment: your path is relative to the php file, is this realy correct?

Comment: You're always executing the `shell_exec` even when the file doesn't exist. As @JarlikStepsto mentioned this line should probably be `$path = '/home/files/java/exec.jar';`

Comment: Changed it, still not working...

Comment: @OscarSjöstedt When you say the file is at `/home/files/java/exec.jar`, why are you using the path 
`/home/server/spigot-1.13.2.jar` in your code?

Comment: You can launch a jar through php with shell_exec. It only needs a jvm on the server. So it's clearly a problem with the path of the jar.